# How can I select the sentence after the last *

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation text and I will select the last sentence after *

Example;
`Home*Development*Mobil and Web Development`

I will only select the last sentece after *  --> (Mobil and Web Development)

Comment: I'm not clear whether this is a Javascript question (so you have a JS string and are trying to get the last substring) or whether it's a CSS question, you are trying to do a CSS select on the last part. Could you clarify for me? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: you can do it in one line `"Home*Development*Mobil and Web Development".split('*').pop()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select `Mobil and Web Development` from the text, you can use `.split(/[*]+/).pop()`.

**Demo**

```js
var n = "Home*Development*Mobil and Web Development".split(/[*]+/).pop();
console.log(n)
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved

Comment: @ABY No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript [Regular express](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for that

```js
let chain = "Home*Development*Mobil and Web Development";

let pattern = /.*\*(.*)$/

let matches = chain.match(pattern);

console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want to do is some styling on the final 'sentence' you can run some JS on startup to find all elements with a particular class, separate out the final part and wrap it in a span and select that:

```js
const selectLasts = document.querySelectorAll('.selectLast');

selectLasts.forEach(selectLast => {
  //note there are 'neater' ways of doing this but each step is deliberately spelled out here to show what is going on
  const text = selectLast.innerHTML;
  const arr = text.split('*');
  const lastText = arr.pop();
  selectLast.innerHTML = arr.join('*');
  const lastEl = document.createElement('span');
  lastEl.innerHTML = '*' + lastText;
  selectLast.appendChild(lastEl);
});
```

```css
.selectLast span {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectLast">Home*Development*Mobil and Web Development</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can insert a child element inside a div like this and then select with CSS.

```css
div > span {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
Home "" Development "" <span>Mobil and Web Development</span>
</div>
```